# Scrolling on a non-Primary Axis

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm having some trouble with the X-axis when making a histogram with OxyPlot.

[image: What I have]

I've plotted everything correctly and the image is what I want/got. I've done this by hiding the category axis and place a linear one over it.

My issue now is that I can't get the data and the axis to move together when I pan or zoom. e.g: 
[image: What happens]

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the rectanglebarseries to draw the histogram. Although this requires the binwidths to be previously calculated.

The rectanglebarseries can be drawn on a linearaxis, so this will eliminate the current problem of the categoryaxis.

Comment: I done it by triggering a mouse event and then moving the Secondary X axis by the amount I moved the Primary. Thanks for your idea though, it would have looked smoother than mine.